# Android, Handler messaging

Tags: android, messaging, handler

I have some very simple code to do with handlers:

```
 Handler seconds=new Handler() { 
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
      bar.incrementProgressBy(5); 
      tView1.setText("r:"+msg);
    } 
  };
```

And my thread:

```
Thread seconds_thread=new Thread(new Runnable() { 
              public void run() { 
                try { 
                  for (int i=0;i<20 && isRunning.get();i++) { 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 

                    Message m = new Message();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("what", 5); // for example
                    m.setData(b);
                    seconds.sendMessage(m);



                  } 
                } 
                catch (Throwable t) { 
                  // just end the background thread 
                } 
              } 
            });
```

As you can see above i am trying to change the value of "`what`" in the message, so i can do different things based on the message, but according to "`tView1.setText("r:"+msg)`" the value of "`what`" is not changing to 5 :(
it is only showing "`what=0`"

How do I change the values of Message so that I can do different things based on the message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must get the data from the Message (as Bundle then as int) you have sent in the handler you do:

```
Handler seconds=new Handler() { 
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
      int sentInt = msg.getData().getInt("what");
      bar.incrementProgressBy(5); 
       tView1.setText("r:"+Integer.toString(sentInt));
    } 
  };
```

Comment: Do some reading about `Bundle` for your second question for your own parameters http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html
It's simple concept to get. (Pair of key and value)

Comment: The way you explained the concept it was easy to understand, as I clicked that link and it came to "parcels" and what not, it kinda flew over my head :(

Comment: Ow. Try it on your own. Try sending String with your name in to that handler and one double that will contain the pi number :) Don't for get key and value concept. :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the message in the same way you got it:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
  bar.incrementProgressBy(5); 
  Bundle data = msg.getData();
  tView1.setText("r:"+data.getInt("what"));
}
```

Sorry for not clarifying that in the previous answer...

P.S. I ignored checking for null for simplicity, but you should check if `data` is null...

Comment: Oops, accepted the above and saw your answer, upvoted it thought! Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't matter to me :) enjoy android!

Comment: Thanks again! It's because of helpful people like you I have a chance to "enjoy android" :)