# update ui in thread

Tags: android

I create a class and extend it from view. also implemented the Runnable interface. In the onTouchEvent i call: `new Thread(this).start()`.
This is my class:

```
public class test extend View interface Runnable{

    ----some code------

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        ----somecode------
        new thread(this).start();
        ----somecode------
    }

    public void run(){
        -----somecode-------
        invalidate();
        -----somecode-------
    }
}
```

but i receive this error:

> only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

How can i fix this?

Comment: Use AsyncTask for asynchronous code

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread - the chosen should solution should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

> postInvalidate()

instead of

> invalidate()

Answer (score 1):

you need to update UI on UIThread, use

```
Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // update UI here
        invalidate();
    }
});
```

Comment: but. runOnUiThread work on Activity. i'm in View(my class extended from View Class).

Comment: if you create your view by constructor, where you pass your activity as a context(`MyView myView = new MyView(MyActivity.this)`), you can get that activity by calling `Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();` in your view

Answer (score 0):

You can use **handler** class to make changes on your UI thread by sending messages.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

[Android, Handler messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804788/android-handler-messaging)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending `View` class which binds to UI-thread, so anything you call in this class will run on the *UI-thread*. However, if you are using a new thread inside that class, then you may rely on its `post(Runnable)` method which will guarantee to run on the view's *UI-thread*. For example:

```
post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will run on UI thread from View class;

```
  post(new Runnable() {     
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **AsyncTask** in android. It start new thread asynchronously and after completion of task it can update current UI without destroying current Activity.

Example Code :

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     // Task which should be completed in background.
     return null;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     // Task which can be done while background process is progressing , such as updatng any UI element of Activity.
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     // Task to do after completion of asynctask.
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

You may also use **runOnUiThread** to do your task.

Both ways are very effective in updating UI in current activity.

**Useful Link** : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
                  http://sharecoding.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/simple-runonuithread-for-update-view-on-android/